# How to display calculated values in IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

I'm working on an online form for attendees of a conference to fill out. Each person enters the amount of minutes they attended for a certain session. The minutes convert to Credit Hours in a form field like so:

```
<div class="col3">
  <form onsubmit="return false" oninput="document.getElementById('MK1').innerHTML = (Math.floor((MC06.value/50) * 2) / 2).toFixed(1)">
    <input name="MC06" id="MC06" onkeyup="disableField06()" type="number" min="0" max="50" placeholder="0-75 minutes" step="any" />
</div>
<div class="col1">
  <output name="MK1" id="MK1">0</output>
  </form>
</div>
```

In case you're wondering, the disableField function disables another session for the same time slot. No problems there. No problems with the placeholder either, thanks to a script I found here.

The hours for Subject Category (MK in this case) are collected in a function when the user clicks the Submit button:

```
var MK1 = document.getElementById("MK1").value;
var MK2 = document.getElementById("MK2").value;
var MK3 = document.getElementById("MK3").value;
var MK4 = document.getElementById("MK4").value;
var MK5 = document.getElementById("MK5").value;
var MK6 = document.getElementById("MK6").value;
document.getElementById("MK").value = parseFloat(MK1) + parseFloat(MK2) + parseFloat(MK3) + parseFloat(MK4) + parseFloat(MK5) + parseFloat(MK6);
```

Finally, the subjects and their total hours per attendant are displayed in a table at the bottom.

```
      <div class="table-row">
          <div class="col2">Marketing:  </div>
          <div class="col4"><input type = "text" id = "MK" name = "MK"></div>
      </div>
```

This works fine in Chrome, but in IE9 (the company browser) I get NaN. How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you create "fiddle" ?

Comment: Also your HTML is invalid

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.

I changed the code for lines like

```
var MK1 = document.getElementById("MK1").value;
```

to

```
var MK1 = document.getElementById("MK1").innerHTML;
```

That worked for the data called back from the input fields. The code that totals all the subjects' credit hours together still returned NaN. I changed those lines back to .value, and it worked! Looks like IE9 has a narrower scope for .value than other browsers.